# Battery Protection + 3.3V regulation circuit - Weird Issues

Tags: voltage-regulator

I just got one of my PCBs back which is designed to work with a 3.7V single-cell LiPo pouch.

The battery is currently at 3.88V

I'm using a DWO1-G battery protection IC combined with an FS8205 dual N-channel FET IC.
The output of this feeds into a HT7333 3.3V regulation IC.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm having some very weird issues. After plugging the battery in, the 3.3V rail is at about 580-600mV.

Now, **if I take my multimeter and use the continuity testing mode and check to see if the pins of the FS8205 are connected to the right place (battery still plugged in), the 3.3V rail magically comes online and my entire circuit works** (another 5V rail dependant on this starts working too).

Now if I go back and do continuity testing on the pins of the FS8205 (again battery plugged in), all the pins of the FS8205 appear to be shorted together.

What is going on? I replaced the FS8205 and same issue happened again. Could it possibly be due to the DW01-G? I triple checked all footprints.

**TLDR: Putting my multimeter and poking around at the FS8205 makes my circuit output stable 3.3V as I wanted. Why?**

**UPDATE: If I short OD and CS of my DWO1-G IC, it fixes everything. But I have to do this everytime battery is re-plugged. Why?**

Comment: Continuity adds a current source + on Red probe so if that enables the pin then the pad is  open.

Comment: What are the OC/OD pin states in this problematic state? Perhaps the DW01 powers up in the over discharge state waiting for a charge cycle?

Comment: The DW01-G data sheet says "Note: When a battery is connected to DW01-G for the first time, it may not enter the normal condition (dischargeable may not be enabled). In this case, short the CS and VSS pins or connect to a charger to restore the normal condition." Have you tried this?

Comment: @sstobbe In problematic state, OD is at -3.617V and falling by 1mV every second almost. OC at 0.247V constant. (Battery at 3.88V). 3.3V rail at 0V.

Comment: @sstobbe Once in the good state (again poking around in continuity at the FS8205), pin OD and pin OC both read 3.88V which happens to be the battery voltage too.

Comment: @JimFischer I have tried that - no luck. I shorted CS and VSS after battery was plugged in.

Comment: Something else I noticed is that after I get the circuit in a good state and a nice 3.3V, if I remove the battery and plug it back in. The 3.3V rail shows 580mV decreasing steadily down towards 0V.

Comment: Okay Update guys: It seems that if I short OD and CS of the DW01+G circuit everything works. But I have to do this everytime battery is plugged. Any ideas? (I also replaced my DWO1+G with a fresh one).

Comment: Any ideas guys?

Comment: I think that there is some mistake in design. I have this same issue. And looking at Yours and mine designs, common drain is unplugged, and two mosfet are configured opposite to each other. And that starts me to thing, if design on the internet is correct at all.